# What is the most efficient way to define a property using Get/Set with a switch for versions?

Tags: c#, properties, switch-statement

I am writing a program to read and write memory from another program, however there are two different versions and the memory values have an offset in one version, but not in the second, so depending on the setting the user has selected (v1 or v2) I need to determine which address to read/write.

As the moment my code is as below, but I dont feel this is very effecient, and replicating this same code makes the class very long when it really doesnt need to be.

Is there a more efficient way of doing all of this:

```cs
public static int Property
{
    get
    {
        switch (Version)
        {
            case Version.v1:
                return Memory.ReadMemory<int>(0xB7CE50 + 0x2680);
            case Version.v2:
                return Memory.ReadMemory<int>(0xB7CE50);
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        switch (Version)
        {
            case Version.v1:
                Memory.WriteMemory<int>(0xB7CE50 + 0x2680, value);
                break;
            case Version.v2:
                Memory.WriteMemory<int>(0xB7CE50, value);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Not all addresses need this offset, but most do, so I also need to account for this, hence I cant just add the 0x2680 value if v2

Comment: `addr = _aLookupTable("propname", version)`? Or 2 different version classes inheriting from a common base?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One obvious way to approach this is to bring the knowledge of what lives where into a central place. You might want to expand your definition of a `Version` to include memory addresses (see below), or you might want to include this information in some other class:

```
public class Version
{
    public int PropertyAddress { get; init; }

    public static Version Version1 { get; } = new()
    {
        PropertyAddress = 0xB7CE50 + 0x2680,
    };

    public static Version Version2 { get; } = new()
    {
        PropertyAddress = 0xB7CE50,
    };

    private Version() { }
}
```

(I've made use of C# 9 syntax here -- adjust if you're targetting an earlier language version).

You can then simplify your property to something like:

```
public static int Property
{
    get => Memory.ReadMemory<int>(Version.PropertyAddress);
    set => Memory.WriteMemory<int>(Version.PropertyAddress, value);
}
```

You could also e.g. put this in a `MemoryAddresses` class (if you wanted to keep `Version` as an enum), and do:

```
private static MemoryAddresses Addresses => Version switch
{
    Version.V1 => MemoryAddresses.V1,
    Version.V2 => MemoryAddresses.V2,
};

public static int Property
{
    get => Memory.ReadMemory<int>(Addresses.PropertyAddress);
    set => Memory.WriteMemory<int>(Addresses.PropertyAddress, value);
}
```

---

If you want to take advantage of the fact that some addresses in one version are offset versions of addresses in the other version, you might do something like:

```
public class Version
{
    public int Offset { get; init; }

    public int Property1Address => 0xB7CE50 + Offset;
    public int Property2Address => 0xB80000 + Offset;
    public int Property3Address { get; init; }

    public static Version Version1 { get; } = new()
    {
        Offset = 0x2680,            // <-- Offset for version 1
        Property3Address = 123456,  // <-- Explicit address for version 1
    };

    public static Version Version2 { get; } = new()
    {
        Offset = 0,                 // <-- No offset for version 2
        Property3Address = 987654,  // <-- Different explicit address for version 2
    };

    private Version() { }
}
```

Comment: Using this method, how would you account for situations where say property 1 = address 1 + offset or just address 1, property 2 = address 2 + offset or just address 2 (so far nice an easy using the above method), but property 3 = either 12345 or 98765 depending on the version being used?

Comment: @RobertEves92 Simply by having `Version.Property3Address` being set to 12345 for Version1 and 98765 for Version2?

Comment: sorry I think i explained that badly. In most cases the version 1 address is "base address" + offset, and the version 2 address is just the base address. But in some cases it would be version 1 is one address, and version 2 is a totally different address rather than just being offset from the other one

Comment: @RobertEves92 Look at how `Version` is instantiated -- there's no assumption that one version's address is offset from the other version's: they're entirely independant. You can write them as base + offset if you want, but there's no requirement to. I'll update my answer to show how you *can* take advantage of the offset thing, which I think is that you're actually asking

Comment: @RobertEves92 See the section at the bottom, which uses an offset

Comment: yup i see it now! Not sure how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to introduce an abstract base class that has concrete implementations of all the properties that are the same for both versions, and abstract declarations for the implementations that differ between the two versions.

For example:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public abstract int PropertyThatDiffersByVersion { get; set; }

    public int PropertyThatIsTheSameForBothVersions
    {
        get
        {
            return Memory.ReadMemory<int>(0xB82677); // I made up the address.
        }

        set
        {
            Memory.WriteMemory<int>(0xB82677, value);
        }
    }
}

public sealed class MyVersion1 : MyBaseClass
{
    public override int PropertyThatDiffersByVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return Memory.ReadMemory<int>(0xB7CE50 + 0x2680);
        }

        set
        {
            Memory.WriteMemory<int>(0xB7CE50 + 0x2680, value);
        }
    }
}

public sealed class MyVersion2 : MyBaseClass
{
    public override int PropertyThatDiffersByVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return Memory.ReadMemory<int>(0xB7CE50);
        }

        set
        {
            Memory.WriteMemory<int>(0xB7CE50, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would create an instance of the appropriate class (`MyVersion1` or `MyVersion2`), and pass it to methods that accepted an object of type `MyBaseClass`.

Comment: Yeah I thought about this initially, but then figured that you're repeating the logic for `Memory.ReadMemory` / `Memory.WriteMemory`, and what you actually want to be doing is separating out the addresses and adding a class hierarchy there. Then I figured doing that means that your class hierarchy is just holding data, not behaviour, and so you can get away with 2 instances, rather than 2 subclasses, which lead to my answer. Still worth mentioning through!